# My VS code interface for Jupyter notebook is very different from the new version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I recently started learning python for data analysis and decided to use VS code for its new Jupyter notebook feature. I installed the extension for python and jupyter notebook in VS code but for some reason my interface is very different from the one in the new update.

I understand this is a small issue but, It's really throwing me off. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using **VS Code Insider**, check if it's titled as `Visual Studio Code- Insiders`:

[image]

Download [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and you'll get the normal layout:

[image]

Comment: ,thank you for the suggestion but i checked and it is not the insiders version. i tried reinstalling both python and jupyter notebook extension but still can get the interface.

Comment: also i checked the Visual code Jupyter notebook extension , and the layout i posted seem to be the layout shown in the extension . So was wondering if it has something to do with that, And also it is the latest update available. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Krish, Did you install python locally? It's required to run jupyter cells and before running it, you should first select python interpreter.